# Azure Pipelines - How to get a pretty Code Coverage Report?

Tags: unit-testing, azure-devops, code-coverage, azure-pipelines

I have finally got my Code Coverage working but it's ugly.

I have googled a lot and almost all samples are with .NET Core.

Unfortunately, my projects are .NET Frameworks.

Is there some tool, extension, or what else anything I could do to get a better report like those listed below.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you install .net core in the server? (the .sln still will be regular .net, just ,net core will be in server), or do you use Microsoft hosted agent (and it's already installed)?

Comment: Hey @ShaykiAbramczyk , Thanks! Let me have a go and tell you the result, I am not sure that the code coverage needs .net core?

Comment: You can use coverlet in the .net framework but you need .net core installed.

Comment: @ShaykiAbramczyk Thanks! It requires to add some additional extensions to the Azure DevOps project's extensions. I will have a go.

Comment: Great. keep us updated :)